# Three.js floating string animation

Tags: css, animation, canvas, three.js, line

I am posting this to find a way to implement an effect. I want to draw a floating line, with moving curves and hover interractions.

An example will speak for itself, the closest example is the project timeline on the home page of this site: https://victoiredouy.com/
You can also see it in the loading bar and everywhere on the site

What I would like to do is to define an array of points where the line must pass, and let it float randomly.

For now, I experimented it with Three.js and CatmullRomCurve3 class, that allows me to set up the mandatory points (see in code snippet below). I defined 6 points on the curve, and It would be quite easy to define some other points for a more natural line, but there are still things missing :

- Random slow floating animation
- Hover interraction
- line drawing animation

Does someone knows how to improve my snippet ?

Thank you ! :)

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0 );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

const scene = new THREE.Scene();


const getPosFromPX = (x, y) => {
    const vec = new THREE.Vector3();
    const pos = new THREE.Vector3();
    vec.set(
        ( x / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
        - ( y / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
        0.5 );
    vec.unproject( camera );
    vec.sub( camera.position ).normalize();
    const distance = - camera.position.z / vec.z;
    pos.copy( camera.position ).add( vec.multiplyScalar( distance ) );
    return pos
}

const getLine = () => {
  const curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
    getPosFromPX(10, 50),
    getPosFromPX(document.body.clientWidth - 50, 50),
    getPosFromPX(document.body.clientWidth - 10, document.body.clientHeight / 2),
    getPosFromPX(50,document.body.clientHeight / 2),
    getPosFromPX(50,document.body.clientHeight -60),
    getPosFromPX(document.body.clientWidth - 50, document.body.clientHeight - 70)
  ] );

  const points = curve.getPoints( 80 );
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
  const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : "#000000" } );
  return new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
}

scene.add(getLine());

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing random on your code what exactly are you looking for? there are sample how to use random here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: @HelderSepulveda yes there is nothing random for now. I want the line to pass by some "mandatory points" that will never move (the points I define in CatmullRomCurve3), and let the line float randomly between those points

Comment: Why are those points mandatory? I feel like the easiest way will be to give some randomization to those points for example you have the starting point (10, 50) why not add some random values to that? anything in the `[ -8 to 8 ]` range would make that a bit random, also you can insert a few random points in between those that are "mandatory" for you

Answer (score -1):

Here expanding on my comment...

I'm adding a small range to those mandatory points to make the final result look random, right now you have six points in the array you pass to CatmullRomCurve3, but you can pass more fully random or just like these ones with a range to keep the line within certain boundaries.

```js
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function getLine() {
  const curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
    new THREE.Vector3(-37 + rand(-8, 8),  20 + rand(-8, 8), 0),
    new THREE.Vector3( 20 + rand(-8, 8),  20 + rand(-8, 8), 0),
    new THREE.Vector3( 37 + rand(-8, 8),   0 + rand(-8, 8), 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-20 + rand(-8, 8),   0 + rand(-8, 8), 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-20 + rand(-8, 8), -16 + rand(-8, 8), 0),
    new THREE.Vector3( 20 + rand(-8, 8), -12 + rand(-8, 8), 0)
  ]);

  const points = curve.getPoints(80);
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
  const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: "#000000" });
  return new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
}

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize(200, 200);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 1, 500);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(getLine());
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

I did clean your code to keep this sample as small as possible